# Taking and Saving a Picture in iOS 6

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios6

First time I have needed to use the camera sense iOS 6, seems as though some things have been been deprecated. Did some research and couldn't find anything but I know its out there. I just need to take a picture, or get from the camera roll and save it to an Image View. Thanks to anyone that has helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

All the helpful information is in the Apple documentation.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

Including the deprecated stuff (see Appendix A).

A more high level overview is the Camera Programming Topics guide:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010400

Comment: Ill take another look at it but what XCode says was deprecated in IOS6 is not present in Appendix A.